# sh: ffmpeg: not found on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ffmpeg, paperclip

I am using paperclip gem and piperclip-ffmpeg on a Rails 3.1 setup.

After deploying to Heroku, I am getting this error after uploading a video.

```
sh: ffmpeg: not found on Heroku
```

My Model

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :asset, :styles => { 
    :medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'video/mpeg' },
    :thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
  }, :processors => [:ffmpeg]
end
```

I'd be surprised if ffmpeg not available on Heroku, but that's may be the problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ffmpeg is not installed on Heroku dynos by default. See [this project](https://github.com/dzello/ffmpeg-heroku/) for a potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying and running Thumbd on Heroku is simple, however, currently in its stock form, video thumbnailing fails due to an internal ImageMagick error.

Follow the detailed instructions here: https://github.com/mubeenh/thumbd/commit/1d2b63a7507263db73d7971176c49e0ea4052e9d